# Simplifing a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### Scenario

I have three elements in this problem. One is an array of ids in this format: (1,3,5,6,8). That array is a list of id of users I want to display. The second element is table that contains user information something simple like: *id name surname email*. The third element is a second table that contains users configuration. There are two parameters in that last table, one is **lid**, and the other is **usraction** (among others, but the important are those two). lid represent a permission type and usraction the value, if the user wants his data to be public there will be a row on that table where **lid=3** and **usraction="accepted"**, also I register the datetime of the action every time the user changes this permission, so each time he change it a new row is added, and in order to retrieve the actual state of the permission i have to retrieve the last row for the user an check the value of usraction like this:

```
SELECT * FROM legallog WHERE uid = '.$user['id'].' AND lid = 3 ORDER BY ABS(`registration` - NOW()) LIMIT 1
```

Then in php:

```
if($queryresult && $queryresult[0]['usraction']=='accepted') //display data
```

### The problem

In the scenario id described how im getting the actual state of the permission set by one user at the time, the problem now is I want to sort of clean an array of ids in one or two sql calls. Lets say I want to print the user information of 4 users, one function gives me the ids in this format: (2,6,8,1), but those users may not want to display their information, using the query I showed before I can make a call to the sql server for each user and then generate a new array, if the users who authorize are 1 and 8 the result array will be (8,1).

The think is whit an array of 100 users I will make 100 calls, and I dont want this, is there a way to solve this in one or two querys?

Comment: So `uid` is not one of the 'important ones'?

Comment: uid are the user User Ids, but for all the users, no matter if they allow to share their data or not

Comment: In my (limited) experience, the most successful questions relating to MySQL are those that take the following format: "Given a dataset like this, how do I obtain a result set like that. You will note that rows x, y, and z are missing because da-di-da-di-da and rows a, b, and c are present because dum-di-dum-di-dum." A nice sqlfiddle to go with it doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query such as this gets you the information you want:

```
select u.*,
       (select usraction from configuration c where c.userid = u.userid and c.lid = 3 order by datetime limit 1
       ) as lastLid3Action
from users u
where u.userid  in (1,3,5,6,8)
```

If you only want "accepted" values, then make this a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select u.*,
             (select usraction from configuration c where c.userid = u.userid and c.lid = 3 order by datetime limit 1
             ) as lastLid3Action
      from users u
      where u.userid  in (1,3,5,6,8)
     ) t
where LastLid3Action = 'Accepted'
```

Comment: Im gettig this error: Every derived table must have its own alias, using this query: select t.* from (select u.*, (select `usraction` from legallog c where c.uid = u.id and c.lid = 3 order by `registration` limit 1) as lastLid3Action from user u where u.id in (10,22,23,25,44,46,48,7))) t where LastLid3Action = Accepted

Comment: @DomingoSL . . . I think you have an extra closing paren in "(10,22,23,25,44,46,48,7))) t".  I think it should be "(10,22,23,25,44,46,48,7) ) t"

Comment: Did that and a modification in the way you sort the data and it goes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have two tables in the first table, where the user information is stored; and the second table, where the user permission is stored. And you want to get information from the first table using permission from the second table, then you need this query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM first-table-name AS a
RIGHT JOIN second-table-name AS b a.uid = b.lid
WHERE uid in (1,3,5,6,8) AND usraction='accepted'
ORDER BY ABS)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You question is somewhat vague, but if you are asking how to select a number of records when you have a list of ids, the answer is:

```
select column, list, goes, here from tablename
where id in (1,5,8,12,413);
```

That will get you the values of the columns you list for just the records that match your array of ids.